# Ansible delegate_to from Linux host to Windows host

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

My playbook runs in Linux and I want to run one particular uri task on a Windows machine. Below is my current task with delegate. It looks like delegate_to is trying to ssh to Windows and it fails.

```
- name: Send a notification to MS Teams
  uri:
    ## Send a notification to MS Teams Channel
    url: "https://abcd.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xyz"
    method: POST
    body:
      title: "Test Title"
      text: "Test text"
  delegate_to: windowsVM
```

Comment: You should [edit] and add your inventory as well as the output which you consider as a fall. See [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to sort it.

When we delegate_to from Linux to Windows, the play assumes all the variables incl connection  variables of Linux Host. So in order to connect to Windows, we need to pass Windows connection vars under the delegate_to block.

```
- name: Send a notification to MS Teams
  uri:
    ## Send a notification to MS Teams Channel
    url: "https://abcd.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xyz"
    method: POST
    body:
      title: "Test Title"
      text: "Test text"
  delegate_to: windowsVM
  vars:
      ansible_port: 5986
      ansible_psrp_cert_validation: ignore
      ansible_psrp_ignore_proxy: yes
      ansible_psrp_negotiate_delegate: yes
      ansible_psrp_connection_timeout: 600
      ansible_psrp_read_timeout: 600
      ansible_psrp_reconnection_backoff: 5
      ansible_psrp_reconnection_retries: 7
      ansible_psrp_user: "{{ userame}}"
      ansible_password: "{{ pass}}"
```